# Get range of period in TradingView

Tags: pine-script

I wrote a script to get highest high from 100 previous period from present period.

so get the range of -100 to 0 then get the highest. 
what I would like is to get in addition  : highest from period -101 to -1 ... -102 to -2

or

get the result of my own script from previous period  .. period-2 ...

I need the result from different range.

this is the beginning

```
hhh = input(high)
lll = input(low)

length1 = input(100)
```

if I could says for exemple : length1 = input range 101 to -1[image]

Answer (score 0):

need to use [] exemple :

hhh = input(high[1])